Integrating button in web portal with Power Bi dashboard button
Greetings fellow stackers,
I am tasked to have a theme button (dark/light) on my web portal integrated with a button in a power bi iframe embedded (private) dashboard within the portal itself.
The idea is when the theme button on the web portal is clicked, the theme button in my power bi dashboard should be triggered to follow the theme. Problem here now is when the theme on the website is changed, the dashboard theme doesn't change.
There is a theme button too in the dashboard and the theme changes when the button is clicked. I am using angular 18.1.1 for the website back end.
TLDR: Syncing 2 buttons at once, when one is triggered (web portal) the other (pbi iframe embedded dashboard) should as well.
[Detailed Image] (https://i.sstatic.net/wt31EdY8.png)
Detailed code
Your help would be very much appreciated!!
Trying to get 2 buttons to sync together, angular web portal and power bi iframe embedded dashboard.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
